# making an activity touchScreen

Tags: android

In my application , i am displaying a splash screen that i want to make touchscreen  and display the next activity .I am a beginner please help me

```
package com.integrated.mpr;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SensitiveFinalActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Button startSensitive;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside oncreat() method add this

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);//In your xml file, main xml  layout android:id="@+id/layout" 
layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i=new Intent(SensitiveFinalActivity.this,YourSecondActivity.class);  
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
           }
 }
```

here YourSecondActivity is the Activity in which u want to go from Splash Screen

Answer (score 1):

Inside `onCreate()` ::

```
 LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);//In your xml file, main xml layout android:id="@+id/layout" 
 layout.setOnClickListener(this);
```

add onclick method

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivityToStart.class);
      startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It will display spalsh screen in period of time or exit on touch

```
Thread mSplashThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                synchronized (this) {
                    // Wait given period of time or exit on touch
                    wait(3000);//ms

                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    YOUR_ACTIVITY.class));
            finish();

        }
    };
    mSplashThread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right way. You just need to add the onClick method and start the next activity:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  // Start next activity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.integrated.mpr;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SensitiveFinalActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Button startSensitive;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Intent i=new Intent(this,<NewActivity>.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
}
}
```